# how to make a word wrapper inside a table?

Tags: tailwind-css, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a word wrapper inside a table row, using Tailwind CSS, and it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

I am:

- Making the table a: "w-full"
- Making the td and the p a "break-all"
- Giving a max width to the tr

This is the code:

```html
      <div className="py-5 ">
        <div className="overflow-x-auto">
          <table className="w-full max-w-4xl mx-auto overflow-hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-300 rounded-lg whitespace-nowrap">
            <thead className="bg-gray-900">
              <tr className="text-left text-white">
                <th className="px-6 py-4 text-lg font-semibold "> n ° </th>
                <th className="px-3 py-4 text-lg font-semibold "> Song </th>
                <th className="px-3 py-4 text-lg font-semibold text-center "> Best Singers </th>
                <th className="px-6 py-4 text-lg font-semibold text-center">  </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
              <tr className="max-w-xs break-words">
                <td className="px-6 py-4">
                  <div className="flex items-center space-x-3">
                    <p>
                      1
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{ maxWidth: '100px' }}
                  className="px-3 py-4 break-all"
                >
                  <p
                    className="break-all"
                  >
                    Vivin la vida loca dsadasdasdasd dasdddddddd saddasdasdad
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td className="px-3 py-4 text-center">
                  <p className="text-blue-600 visited:text-purple-600 hover:text-blue-800 hover:underline">
                    Donkey
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td className="px-3 py-4 text-center">
                  <p className="text-blue-600 visited:text-purple-600 hover:text-blue-800 hover:underline">
                    Ricky Martin
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You just need to remove the `whitespace-nowrap` from the table, then it should work.

Uploaded the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ewzbi6?file=src/App.js

[image: example with word wrap]

Answer (score 0):

Might be another part of your styling affecting things here. This works for me:

Don't mean this as an answer, just can't attach pics to comments.

[image]

Comment: But I want it to the resposive and that the text is wrapped acording to the table actual size

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found many staff that affected my style so I did it with JavaScript to show the first 5 words and append `...` in the end using `split`.